# How can I specify a smaller block size for a Ramdisk?

Tags: filesystem, git

I use a ramdisk to speed up a git repository with a lot (> 60k) of small (~200 bytes) files.

Is there a way to create a ramdisk with a smaller block size?

Comment: How do you specify the ramdisk now?

Comment: diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "ramdisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1165430`

Comment: I would look at hdiutil resize - however does a ramdisk really help in your scenario - test the speed as disk caching might do enough  + what happens when osx or something else crashes don't you lose work and defeat the object of version control?

Comment: I currently fail to commit the git repository under 10.7 due to a timeout (> 3h) whereas I can finish the exact same operations in 10mins on a standard Ubuntu VirtualBox image running on the very same machine.

Comment: In this case it does not defeat the versioning system since I want to do some expensive rebaseing and version comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary: I don't believe this is possible, at least not for volumes formatted as HFS+.

My current understanding is that HFS+ chooses its file system block size (separate from the physical device block size) according to a fixed [default allocation block size](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA37344) that cannot be manually overruled.

[image: HFS+ Default Allocation Block Size]

Discussions in other forums spanning from 2002 to 2011 ( [CompGroups](http://compgroups.net/comp.sys.mac.system/how-to-format-hfs+-with-larger-block-size/1151496), [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=186487&page=3) among others) suggest using [newfs_hfs(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/newfs_hfs.8.html), which has a `-b <blocksize>` option, to manually set the block size when creating a new file system.

I tried using `newfs_hfs`  on various kinds of partitions, on both .dmg diskimages and on physical SATA hard drives (through SATA<->USB interface) and with various file systems (HFS+, FAT16, FAT32.)  When I ran `newfs_hfs` with different -b sizes (512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192,) indeed it reported success in creating the filesystems with the specified block sizes. I could mount & read/write these volumes normally.

But when I examine the test volumes with `diskutil info <diskname>` (where `<diskname>` is disk1, disk4, or whatever your disk is), I always see:

```
Total Size:               104.9 MB (104857600 Bytes) (exactly 204800 512-Byte-Blocks)
Volume Free Space:        102.4 MB (102385664 Bytes) (exactly 199972 512-Byte-Blocks)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
```

Noting that the end of the `newfs_hfs(8)` man page includes this tidbit:

```
HISTORY
The newfs_hfs command appeared in Mac OS X Server 1.0 .  As of Mac OS X
10.6, this utility no longer generates HFS standard file systems.
```

It would appear that OS X 10.8 (and probably 10.7, and perhaps earlier versions) overrides whatever block size `newfs_hfs` claims to create, in favor of default sizes imposed by a higher authority. (??)

---

One article I came across suggested using OS X's software-RAID utility to create a RAID mirror. Software RAID allows one to specify a RAID **stripe** size, but as this is generally geared towards improving throughput for large files rather than tiny ones, I believe the minimum RAID stripe size is 4KB - not useful for your purposes.